# Functions as parameters (with parameters) -- JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have some OO javascript that looks like so:

```
function someFunction(a, b, c) {
  // do something with a, b, and c
}

function theLoader() {
    loadFunction: someFunction,
    load: function() {
      // invoke the loadFunction with the proper parameter set
    }
}

var myLoader = new theLoader();
myLoader.load();
```

Let's assume that 'theLoader' is expected to be abstract and generic.  I could call it and set the 'loadFunction' to almost anything, so I don't know what the arguments are going to be at any given time.  The 'load' method must invoke the 'loadFunction' and somehow be able to get an argument set to it....

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?  If this is a bad way to go about it, we can totally refactor the code.  I'd like to keep restrictions off of the 'loadFunction' so I don't have to code loader functions in a special way.

At the end of the day, I'd like to package theLoader into it's own .js file and not have to monkey with it.

So -- if you know the answer, help a brother out!!

Thanks,
g

Answer (score 3):

Use `apply` or `call` to perform the function call. A description of the functions can be found here:

- http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/function.shtml

Comment: I've been looking into the apply.  still, can I just use 
loadFunction.apply(this, arguments) given that loadFunction isn't the actual function name?

Comment: Yes, as apply and call are both methods of the Function object.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your `loadFunction` follow an interface, and use polymorphism to call it. Having said that, you do have a real requirement to capture the arguments to `someFunction` in *some* way.

Can you allow the `load` function to take the parameters that `loadFunction` requires?

```
myLoader.load(1, '2', 'foo'); // calls this.loadFunction(1, '2', 'foo')
```

Or, allow `theLoader` to take them in the constructor?

```
function theLoader() {
    this.loadFunctionArgs = arguments;
}

theLoader.prototype = {
    loadFunction: someFunction,
    load: function() {
        return this.loadFunction.apply(this, this.loadFunctionArgs)
    }
}

var myLoader = new theLoader(1, '2', 'foo');
myLoader.load(); // calls someFunction(1, '2', 'foo')
```

I haven't the slightest idea if this is a good design for your app. It's certainly ok to do in JavaScript (as far as the language goes I mean).

Comment: That is good advice.  I tried to keep it somewhat abstract for simplicity's sake, but it would really look more like this (next comment)

Comment: function customerDataLoader(customerID) {  stuff }
function customerInvoiceLoader(customerID, orderNumber) {stuff}

custLoader = new theLoader({loadFunction: customerDataLoader});
invoiceLoader = new theLoader({loadFunction: invoiceDataLoader});

Parameter values are not static.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
function theLoader() {
    this.load = function() {
        if (this.loadFunction) {
            return this.loadFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
}
// Usage
var loader = new Loader();
loader.loadFunction = someFunction;
loader.load(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Also, you were mixing object literal notation with function literals, which is incorrect.

Comment: Helgi - thanks for the tips.  I was a bit fuzzy about dot notation and object literal notation.  Your example and pointer were a tremendous help.