# JQuery deferred changes "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm attempting to have a javascript object run a deferred method and when it's .done() call a function in that same object.  I'm having issues because "this" becomes the deferred object instead of the object that called it.

```
PageObject.prototype.successFunction = function() {
  console.log(arguments);
  return console.log(this.name + " Success function called");
};

PageObject.prototype.loadPage = function(url) {
  return $.when($.mobile.loadPage("pages/" + url))
    .done(this.successFunction);
};

var pg = new PageObject();
pg.loadPage("test.html");
```

How do I send "this" into the successFunction?  This PageObject is going to be extended by others as well, so knowing "this" when running successFunction will be very handy.

It seems simple, and probably has a simple answer.  I was looking into .apply() but I'm not sure it helped.  This post on stack overflow was helpful a little bit, but it broke the minute I put it into the .done() function.

[Functions as parameters (with parameters) -- JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737802/functions-as-parameters-with-parameters-javasript)

Comment: FWIW, the deferred object is not changing this, it's just how functions work. The value of this is not determined by how/where  a function is defined, but how it is called.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

jQuery's [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) will return a function bound to a specific context:

```
PageObject.prototype.loadPage = function(url) {
  return $.when($.mobile.loadPage("pages/" + url))
    .done($.proxy(this.successFunction, this));
};
```

There is also ES5's [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) which operates similarly but needs to be shimmed in older browsers

```
PageObject.prototype.loadPage = function(url) {
  return $.when($.mobile.loadPage("pages/" + url))
    .done(this.successFunction.bind(this));
};
```

`apply` and `call` can execute a function immediately with the specified context, but `proxy` and `bind` return a function that can be used later or passed to other functions.

Comment: Fantastic answer, this is exactly what I needed (and I was going crazy trying to figure it out).  I ended up using the $.proxy version you posted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `this` "variable" in JavaScript is called the "calling object" and is determined when its enclosing function is called (not when it's defined). It can be set a few different ways:

1. You can set it by using the `.` operator (e.g. `myObject.myFunction()`)
2. You can set it by using a function's `call()` or `apply()` methods
3. You can (under ES5) bind it permanently by using the function's `bind()` method
4. It will default to the global object if none of the above methods set it to something else

The important thing to understand is that (aside from method 3 above), it's all about how the function is called when it's called, not how it's referenced, not how it's stored, not where it's created.

In your case, you're passing `this.successFunction` as a function reference to be called by jQuery, but it doesn't call it that way (because it just got a reference to the function, not any information on how that function should be called).

There are a few fancy tricks you can use with jQuery's `$.proxy()` or ES5's `.bind()` methods, but when it comes down to it, the most straightforward way to handle it is to simply retain `this` through a closure-scoped variable and use a function wrapper:

```
PageObject.prototype.loadPage = function(url) {
    var self = this;
    return $.when($.mobile.loadPage("pages/" + url))
            .done(function () { self.successFunction(); });
};
```

Note that we're using method 1 to explicitly bind `successFunction`'s calling object to be the same as loadPage's calling object. It's short, simple, clear, works fine under ES3, and doesn't depend on jQuery.

Comment: +1 for what goes on behind the scenes, but I tend to prefer the fancy tricks, if available, as it keeps the code cleaner.